# What is the best caching module for lighttpd?

Tags: php, wordpress, lighttpd

I'm using lighttpd web server and now I have to install wordpress to run my blog.

I am very concerned about caching. I know there is a good module for php named **XCACHE** but I don't understand if I have to install this module or only install "**super cache**" wordpress plugin.

What are the differences? Can run together?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Xcache is an opcode cache. PHP compiles every time it is run. So Xcache would cache its code in the machine language and store it in RAM. This is greatly speed up execution of the script as it doesn't need recompiling and also it is stored in RAM (less i/o). However, this means that all your pages would be still dynamic, which means that your pages would be generated everytime by executing the php code on there.

If you install super cache plugin, that will cache the html of the page. It will store the html and then serve that to the user. This means that the data would be static for the caching time and not dynamically generated for every user.

It would be best to use both for the maximum performance results. But you would need Xcache installed on your server to be able to use the Xcache plugin in wordpress.

Comment: @user658911 which WP Plugin do I have to install? Xcache for WP or Super cache? I also have intalled xcache on the server...

Comment: Install xcache and supercache if you have xcache installed on the server